# problem with the chi-square table while solving hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

i was looking up the chi-square table for n=4, and 0.98 probability but i couldn't find a column of 0.98 so what should i do to find out the value?

The question is to find out if the null hypothesis will be rejected.

H0 : variance = 2 , Ha : variance < 2.

sample variance = 0.716

sample size = 5

type 1 error probability = 0.02

and that's why i need to find out 0.98 with df=4 in the table. Please help.

Comment: Decades ago extensive books of tables were published for occasions like this. Nowadays on-the-shelf software is used. The package called R does this routinely. So do lots of other packages, but you can download R for free. Here's something google led me to: http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/chi-square.aspx Put in $0.98$ in the "cumulative probability" box and the degrees of freedom in the appropriate box, and leave the "critical value" box empty, and press "calculate".

Comment: Thanks man. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized you have sample size of $5$ and $4$.. Usually sample size is denoted by n so that is confusing for the viewers. if the sample size **is** $5$, then the degrees of freedom (df) is $4$, which in this case:

```
 qchisq(.98,4) = 11.67
```

**Confidence Interval**

You could create a 98% confidence interval estimate of the variance as follows:

I'm doing to define these first since I don't know how to do subscripts in here, so let

$$X^2 \left(1-\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) = X^2(.99)$$
$$and$$

$$X^2 \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) = X^2(.01)$$

*here we used df = 4*...

Then, using a chi square table, I obtain the values:

$$X^2(.99) = 13.28$$
$$and$$
$$X^2(.01) = .297$$

The 98% CI for the estimate of the variance is given by:

$$\frac{(n-1) s^2}{X^2(0.99)}\leq \sigma ^2\leq \frac{(n-1) s^2}{X^2(.01)}$$

Thus,

$$\frac{(5-1) 0.716}{13.28}\leq \sigma ^2\leq \frac{(5-1) 0.716}{.297}$$

The 98% CI for the estimate of the variance is:

$$.2156 \leq \sigma ^2 \leq 9.64$$
$$and$$
$$.464 \leq \sigma \leq 3.105$$

**Hypothesis Test**

So notice that since the alternative hypothesis is "<", this means we will be conducting a lower (one sided) hypothesis test, meaning our critical value will be X^2(.01) = .297, and if our observed chi statistic exceeds this value, then the Null is not rejected

We can compute the observed Chi Square statistic based on the data you have using the formula:

## $$X^2=\frac{(n-1) s^2}{\sigma ^2}$$

Using those $3$ values I computed a chi square statistic of $1.43$

Since $1.43$ > $.297$, the null hypothesis is not rejected.. Therefore, there is not enough evidence to claim that the population variance  is less than 2, at the .02 significance level.

Phew!!

Comment: thanks man, this is helpful. So it seems like the only way is to use software. Luckily i won't have this problem in the next part which is to find out the upper and lower bound since as i remember, i just need to use (error probability / 2), am i right?

Comment: For the "non standard" values like .98, yes.. The values like .90, .95 and .99 can always be looked up in a table.. As to your second question, you are right, but upper is 1 - (error probability/2). lower is still (error probability/2). It sounds like you might need to refer to a table, because those values will be .01 and .99..And you're welcome!

Comment: @Jack Because I'm going to solve the next part of the problem for you in my answer above, that way you can check your work and it might be useful to others.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brandon,  you've done everything for me!

Comment: @Jack You're welcome! The only thing missing (and most important) is a p-value, though I don't know how to solve for that by hand (usually done in calculator or something)

Comment: thanks alot, but when i check to table again, it seems like 11.37 is more like the value between (0.025,4) and (0.01,4) but not the number with high error probability, it is kind of wired.